# How to make the curl command of buildroot support nghttp2?

Tags: curl, libcurl, buildroot, nghttp2

I'm about to let my curl command support http2 protocol. As far as I know, nghttp2 is a package of http2. But there are many solutions just on Ubuntu, CentOS, MacOS. But the resource from web didn't mention too much on buildroot.

So, could someone tell me how to let curl in buildroot supports the nghttp2?  Many thanks.

Comment: You just need to add [nghhtp2](https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2) to BR and handle nghttp2 dependency in `package/libcurl/libcurl.mk`. See BR's [documentation](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_autotools_based_packages).

Comment: Thanks for your message. I had checked the libcurl.mk and I found the script in it. 
===================================
# Configure curl to support http2
ifeq ($(BR2_PACKAGE_LIBNGHTTP2),y)
LIBCURL_DEPENDENCIES += libnghttp2
LIBCURL_CONF_OPTS += --with-nghttp2=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr
endif
===================================

Comment: It means I need to import libnghttp2 under buildroot/package as well.
And here is what I get from libnghttp2.mk

Comment: ############
#
# libnghttp2.mk
#
############

LIBNGHTTP2_VERSION = v1.23.1
LIBNGHTTP2_SITE = $(call github,nghttp2,nghttp2,$(LIBNGHTTP2_VERSION))
LIBNGHTTP2_LICENSE = ISC
LIBNGHTTP2_LICENSE_FILES = COPYING
LIBNGHTTP2_INSTALL_STAGING = YES
LIBNGHTTP2_INSTALL_TARGET  = YES
LIBNGHTTP2_AUTORECONF = YES

$(eval $(autotools-package))

Comment: I think it wasn't a properly mk file.   Can't see any download URL.  
Even I enabled this lib,  curl still can't see the http2 in Feature. ...


So I started to find out another solution from ther Internet...:(

Comment: It is better to send such questions directly to BR's maling list including your files.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm just try buildroot recently. Eventually, I found that everything you modified from buildroot's menuconfig, you have to remove the package from buildroot/output/build path.
So that you will have properly compile  with your expectation.